# How do I print out every value of data I have inside my csv file in Pandas using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pokemon data that is saved as a csv file. I just wanna say that I am a complete novice in here so this might be a very basic error but I'd still like it to be posted. I know how to print and make a dataframe, I've tried that but the problem is that I wanna see every single bit of data inside my csv file. The csv file has 800 rows x 12 columns. And whenever I print it out in my jupyter notebook it just shows 4 of the first values and 4 of the last values. Which is not what I want. I tried both print it directly `df`, using the `print()`, and also creating a dataframe `datas = pd.DataFrame(df) datas` . But all of which seemed to do the same thing.

TL;DR: I wanna print out every data inside my csv file in jupyter but it only prints out 4 of the first values and 4 of the last values.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

And in the next cell you can print df

```
print(df)
```

Comment: I used jupyter notebook and I did search this but how do I callout my dataframe? Because it just None to me since I think I'm supposed to call it out

Comment: Run these 2 lines in one cell and in the next cell just print your data frame normally